# Upgrade triggers custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I have a custom action that meant for maintenance of installation:

```
<Custom Action="caPostMaintenanceConfiguration" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
```

But this action is being executed during upgrade from original MSI during its uninstall. Is it a bug in Wix infrastructure? Is there a way to have control over that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the custom action is in the originally installed MSI as well as in your upgrade, then it will run during the uninstall of the older product. The condition will evaluate to true because the older product is still installed at the time you are uninstalling it, and WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED won't be set during the uninstall.